# Get coordinates of displayed part of a website with selenium/webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Assume I've got a HTML page which is 1000 pixel wide, and 2000 pixel high. My browser is capable to display just 500 wide by 400 pixel high.

If i scroll e.g. the page 100 pixel down and 200 pixel right, how can i get the coordinates of the:

- upper left corner of the displayed part of the page
- upper right corner of the displayed part of the page
- lower left corner of the displayed part of the page
- lower right corner of the displayed part of the page

I'm trying to do this with java and javascript and selenium/webdriver.

Comment: Show how you're `trying to do this with java and javascript and selenium/webdriver`

Comment: Acutall i can get following values.
Hight of the Browser window
int winHeight = initial_size.getHeight();


System Resulution
Long sysResulution = (Long) js.executeScript("return screen.height;");


Hight of the displayed part of the page
Long htmlHightDisplayed = (Long) js.executeScript("return window.innerHeight;");


Hight of the complete page
Long htmlHightComplete = (Long) js.executeScript("return document.body.scrollHeight;");